# Phonegap verification error: Unable to validate your application, the package does not contain an info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, verification

I have just finished my application. It runs fine on all devices that I tested it on. It archives successfully as well. However, when I try to validate it in the Xcode organizer I am met with the following errors:

-Unable to validate your application: The info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleShortVersionString key

-Unable to validate your application: The package does not contain an info.plist

I checked my project files, and I do see an info.plist file.

Any help? Please keep in mind that as I am new to this, step by step explanations will be the most useful resources for me to understand.

Comment: This error has been resolved. Turns out this is an Xcode 6 problem. I fixed it by setting my build and version identifiers manually under the "General" tab in project settings. Hopefully that will help someone out in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a screen shot that might help someone out based on @Ian's answer. It's not just for Phonegap.

[image]